# Connect Orion with specific database

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have suffered a reboot on the unexpected server, when restarting the contextrboker it does not connect with the old features at reboot. if I enter Mongodb, two databases appear: orion and orion-tests.

I would like to connect with orion-tests, this is where I had all the entities.

When I created a new entity with Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath, I always created a new database with that entity, but at the moment it adds everything to Orion.

What is the problem? How can i fix this? I have more than 100 entities created in the previous database.

EDIT01

This is the information:

```
ps -ax | grep contextBroker
 9275 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto contextBroker
19825 ?        Ssl    0:45 contextBroker
```

Comment: I think I know what can be the cause, but to confirm I'd need to know how do you run Orion. Could you edit your question post to add that information, please? Typically, the ouput of `ps -ax | grep contextBroker` in the system where Orion runs.

Comment: This is the information:

ps -ax | grep contextBroker
  9275 pts / 2 S + 0:00 grep --color = auto contextBroker
19825? Ssl 0:45 contextBroker

Comment: Difficult to see in the comment line... Could you edit your question post and include it there, properly formated? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I just edited the post

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix to connect Orion to another database use the `-db` parameter.

```
docker run fiware/orion -db orion-tests
```

To **really** fix the issue read the section on [Database Administration](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/database_admin/index.html), regularly take a database dump of your entities. All you need to do is to `mongorestore` the data from `orion-test` into `orion`

```
mongodump old_database
mongorestore --db new_database ./dump/old_database
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run Orion with multiservice flag enabled in order to process `fiware-service` header. Try using `contextBroker -multiservice` instead of `contextBroker`.